# How to generate a list of all metadata objects deployed in SAS Platform?

Tags: sas, sas-metadata

I have a production environment server using SAS Platform. 
Is there a way to generate a report of a list of all metadata objects deployed in this production environment?

More accurately, is there an easy point-and-click way using one of the SAS Tools (e.g. SAS EG, SAS DI, SAS SMC)? If not I am open to the "right" way of doing it.

Comment: Yes, there is, using SAS Open Metadata Interface, however it would be better if you were more specific about the type objects you wish to report on. For example, Users, Tables, Libraries?

Comment: I think I need two kinds of reports, 
1) one on all the metadata objects (which can include Users, Libraries, ACTs, Tables, etc) deployed on a system
2) one on just the metadata objects in the SAS Metadata (exclude Users, ACTs, etc)

Comment: You could export a package from DI Studio containing everything in the SAS Metadata Repository, but it may take a while to analyse all of the connections between elements. Alternatively I think there's a way to get this information from SAS Management Console, but I can't confirm as I don't have either application to hand.

Answer (score 1):

you can try using the %MDSECDS macro which is shipped whit SAS/Foundation. This macro provide a lot of informations like you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking to extract a list of all the objects that can be seen in the folder tree, this [macro](https://github.com/macropeople/macrocore/blob/master/meta/mm_tree.sas) from the [macrocore](https://github.com/macropeople/macrocore) library will do it:

```
 %mm_tree(outds=allmyobjects)
```

Note - if you have multiple repositories, you will need to run this for each (and set `options metarepository=YOURREPO;` each time).

A macro to get the list of repos is available [here](https://github.com/macropeople/macrocore/blob/master/meta/mm_getrepos.sas).